# How to create BufferedImage with a separate alpha raster

Tags: java, swt, awt, bufferedimage, raster

Motivation:
My goal is to convert AWT `BufferedImage` to SWT `ImageData` in the most efficient way. Typical answer to this question is pixel by pixel conversion of the whole picture, that is O(n^2) complexity. Much more efficient would be if they could exchange whole pixel matrix as it is. `BufferedImage` seems to be very flexible in determining in detail how colors and alpha are encoded.

To provide you with a wider context, I wrote a SVG icon on demand rasterizer, using Apache Batik, but it is for SWT (Eclipse) application. Batik renders only to a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`, but SWT components require `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image`.

Their backing raster objects: `java.awt.image.Raster` and `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData` represent exactly same thing, they are just wrapper around a 2D array of byte values representing pixels. If I can make one or the other to use came color encoding, voila, I can reuse the backing array as it is.

I got pretty far, this works:

```
// defined blank "canvas" for Batik Transcoder for SVG to be rasterized there
public BufferedImage createCanvasForBatik(int w, int h) {
    new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
}

// convert AWT's BufferedImage  to SWT's ImageData to be made into SWT Image later
public ImageData convertToSWT(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
    DataBuffer db = bufferedImage.getData().getDataBuffer();
    byte[] matrix = ((DataBufferByte) db).getData();

    PaletteData palette =
            new PaletteData(0x0000FF, 0x00FF00, 0xFF0000); // BRG model

    // the last argument contains the byte[] with the image data
    int w = bufferedImage.getWidth(); 
    int h = bufferedImage.getHeight();

    ImageData swtimgdata = new ImageData(w, h, 32, palette);
    swtimgdata.data = matrix; // ImageData has all field public!!

    // ImageData swtimgdata = new ImageData(w, h, 32, palette, 4, matrix);  ..also works
    return swtimgdata;
}
```

It all works except transparency :(

It looks like `ImageData` requires (always?) alpha to be a separate raster, see `ImageData.alphaData` from color raster, see `ImageData.data`; both are `byte[]` types.

Is there a way how to make `ImageData` to accept `ARGB` model? That is alpha mixed with other colors? I doubt so I went the other way. To make `BufferedImage` to use separate arrays (aka rasters or "band") for colors and alpha. The `ComponentColorModel` and `BandedRaster` seem to intended exactly for these things.

So far I got here:

```
public BufferedImage createCanvasForBatik(int w, int h) {
    ColorSpace cs = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB);
    int[] nBits = {8, 8, 8, 8}; // ??
    ComponentColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(cs, nBits, true, false, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
    WritableRaster raster = Raster.createBandedRaster(
        DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, w, h, 4, new Point(0,0));
    isPremultiplied = false;
    properties = null;
    return new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, isPremultiplied, properties);
}
```

That creates a separate raster (band) for alpha but also for every color separately, so I end up with 4 bands (4 rasters) which is again unusable for SWT Image.  **Is it possible to create a banded raster with 2 bands: one for colors in RGB or BRG, and one for alpha only?**

Comment: Is the SWT BGR image data interleaved? It seems so from the first part of your question. If so, it doesn't make much sense to make a banded raster. You'll need to create some sort of custom `DataBuffer` and/or `SampleModel` I think, with interleaved BGR storage and a discrete alpha storage. Of course, it would be simpler if the SWT image data allowed interleaved alpha as well...

Comment: Thanks @haraldK, you summed up nicely what I am asking for, perhaps in better words: How to create such custom DataBuffer and/or SampleModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know SWT in detail, but based on my understand of the API doc, the below should work:

The trick is to use a custom `DataBuffer` implementation that masquerades as a "banded" buffer, but internally uses a combination of interleaved RGB and separate alpha array for storage. This works nicely with the standard `BandedSampleModel`. You will lose any chance of special (hardware) optimizations that are normally applied to `BufferedImage`s using this model, but that should not matter as you are using SWT for display anyway.

I suggest you create your SWT image first, and then "wrap" the color and alpha arrays from the SWT image in the custom data buffer. If you do it this way, Batik should render directly to your SWT image, and you can just throw away the `BufferedImage` afterwards (if this is not practical, you can of course do it the other way around as well, but you may need to expose the internal arrays of the custom data buffer class below, to create the SWT image).

Code (important parts are the `SWTDataBuffer` class and `createImage` method):

```
public class SplitDataBufferTest {
    /** Custom DataBuffer implementation using separate arrays for RGB and alpha.*/
    public static class SWTDataBuffer extends DataBuffer {
        private final byte[] rgb; // RGB or BGR interleaved
        private final byte[] alpha;

        public SWTDataBuffer(byte[] rgb, byte[] alpha) {
            super(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, alpha.length, 4); // Masquerade as banded data buffer
            if (alpha.length * 3 != rgb.length) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad RGB/alpha array lengths");
            }
            this.rgb = rgb;
            this.alpha = alpha;
        }

        @Override
        public int getElem(int bank, int i) {
            switch (bank) {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                    return rgb[i * 3 + bank];
                case 3:
                    return alpha[i];
            }
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(String.format("bank %d >= number of banks, %d", bank, getNumBanks()));
        }

        @Override
        public void setElem(int bank, int i, int val) {
            switch (bank) {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                    rgb[i * 3 + bank] = (byte) val;
                    return;
                case 3:
                    alpha[i] = (byte) val;
                    return;
            }

            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(String.format("bank %d >= number of banks, %d", bank, getNumBanks()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // These are given from your SWT image
        int w = 300;
        int h = 200;
        byte[] rgb = new byte[w * h * 3];
        byte[] alpha = new byte[w * h];

        // Create an empty BufferedImage around the SWT image arrays
        BufferedImage image = createImage(w, h, rgb, alpha);

        // Just to demonstrate that it works
        System.out.println("image: " + image);
        paintSomething(image);
        showIt(image);
    }

    private static BufferedImage createImage(int w, int h, byte[] rgb, byte[] alpha) {
        DataBuffer buffer = new SWTDataBuffer(rgb, alpha);
        // SampleModel sampleModel = new BandedSampleModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, w, h, 4); // If SWT data is RGB, you can use simpler constructor
        SampleModel sampleModel = new BandedSampleModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, w, h, w,
                new int[] {2, 1, 0, 3}, // Band indices for BGRA
                new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0});

        WritableRaster raster = Raster.createWritableRaster(sampleModel, buffer, null);
        ColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB), true, false, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
        return new BufferedImage(colorModel, raster, colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
    }

    private static void showIt(final BufferedImage image) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
                label.setOpaque(true);
                label.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                frame.add(label);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static void paintSomething(BufferedImage image) {
        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        int qw = w / 4;
        int qh = h / 4;

        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.fillOval(0, 0, w, h);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(5, 5, qw, qh);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("R", 5, 30);

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(5 + 5 + qw, 5, qw, qh);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("G", 5 + 5 + qw, 30);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(5 + (5 + qw) * 2, 5, qw, qh);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("B", 5 + (5 + qw) * 2, 30);

        g.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Woohaa! It works. I works even with Apache Batik. Thank you! Few tiny changes, I had to expose `rgb` and `alpha` arrays, On SWT side, I have to use `bufferedImage.getRaster()` and NOT `getData()`; only `getRaster()` returns `SWTDataBuffer` with `getRgb()` and `getAlpha()` returning the arrays.

Comment: For anyone interested, here are working sources: https://bitbucket.org/espinosa/org.bitbucket.espinosa.svg.icon/src/59f50b81a0ac3521d997e93a752ad351192397a3/src/org/bitbucket/espinosa/svg/icon/swt/BufferedImageToSwtImageDataConverter2.java?at=alternative-buffimg2swt 
and 
https://bitbucket.org/espinosa/org.bitbucket.espinosa.svg.icon/src/59f50b81a0ac3521d997e93a752ad351192397a3/src/org/bitbucket/espinosa/svg/icon/swt/BufferedImageToSwtImageConverter2.java?at=alternative-buffimg2swt

Comment: @Espinosa Yes, `getData()` creates a *copy* of the data in the raster, while `getRaster()` returns the current raster. So you definitively want to use `getRaster()` here.